# Build vote system using Laravel 5

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I'm trying to build voting system for my web page (Laravel 5). Now, any user can vote multiple times, I want to fix it.

Here is my code in php:

```
public function addVote()
{
    $bikepoint = $this->bikepoint->find($id);
    $userid = \Sentry::getUser()->id;
    $votesid = \DB::table('bikepoints')->select('votesuid')->where('votesuid', 'LIKE' , $userid)->get();
    if (...) {
        $bikepoint->votes = $bikepoint->votes + 1;
        $bikepoint->votesuid = $bikepoint->votesuid . $userid . '; ';
        echo 'Success!';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Fail!';
    }
    $bikepoint->save();
}
```

My DB table:

```
id  title   votes  votesuid
1   point1  2      93; 22;
2   point2  3      92; 28; 47;
3   point3  45     ...
4   point4  32     ...
5   point5  12     ...
```

So when user click the "Add vote" button, a function adds its ID to the `votesuid` field and one vote to the `votes` field.

I want to check if the user has already voted by checking if his ID is placed in the `votesuid` field. And, if so, the user cannot vote anymore.

For example, users with IDs `92`, `28` and `47` should not be able to vote another time.

Comment: Yowch. Don't store a comma-separated list of votes. Store a row per vote, and put a unique key on user+vote.

Comment: What @ceejayoz said. If you follow his suggestion, you could also limit the casting of multiple votes by placing a `unique` index on the voting table.

Comment: Thanks in advance) I'll rebuild entire vote system)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others in the comments, yes, you do need to change your system so that each vote has it's own record on a table.

So create a Votes table and a Laravel model class for it, and give your Users model class a `hasMany()` relationship to Votes.

That's actually not too much work, is it?

But now then the solution to your question becomes trivially easy -- ie:

```
$votes = Sentry::getUser()->votes;
```

As things stand, you would need to do sub-string `LIKE` queries, which are much harder to write, and will also give you major performance problems when your DB starts getting bigger, so yes, you definitely need to be refactoring it now.